How to Autotune Batch Size When Inserting to Big Query Table from SQL Alchemy?
Code Example
The objective is very simple. A list of dictionaries (each dictionary having the same keys, and values data types) is to be inserted into a bigquery table using SQL alchemy ORM. The relevant part is presented below.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8


from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, func
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query, Session

values:List[Dict[str, str]] # The rows to be inserted into the table

# The session is formed from SQL Alchemy engine using bigquery dialect
session.execute(statement=table.insert(values=values)) # This payload < 10 MB


The SQL dialect used by the engine is called bigquery.
Challenge
As my inserts from a moderate sized dataframe (1.2 million rows, each converted to the dictionary) were failing I discovered the followings after reading some documentation.

The dialect uses the Bigquery storage write API under the hood
The API has a payload ceiling of 10MB per request

Hence, to write 1.2 million rows, I had to batch my calls instead of inserting them all with a single call to the storage write.
Question
More calls mean higher latency, basically, the overhead of initiating and terminating multiple connections? So that means I should strive to send as close to 10MB as possible in each call?
Is there a smart way to tell this to SQL alchemy? Or else, the two options to me are

Pick a very small batch size, like 32 or 64, then stick to it, no matter how many separate calls it takes?
Analyse the table schema, and each row to make sure every call has just close to 10 MB of data, adjusting how many rows to insert in each call. This makes the code less repeatable, and each table needs its own analysis, which I would avoid if possible.

So I am looking for some ways to tell SQL Alchemy to make each payload as close to 10MB as possible. Any parameter to support this scenario? Essentially, something like option 2 above, but repeatable via a python function that is agnostic of table schema.
